# K-Means Clustering on Distributed System

Tags: clustering, k-means

Can anyone explain how the k-means clustering algorithm converges on distributed systems? It seems that each node in our hadoop cluster would simply find a local optimum. How do we update across multiple nodes?

Answer (score 1):

At each iteration, local results are merged on a central node. You do not independently run k-means on each node! 
The data volume is constant in the data set size, and the CPU cost is neglible,  so this is very favorable. k-means is embarassingly parallel,  and all the advanced methos aim at achieving *sublinear* processing time.